# How do you make a python script globally executable? OSX

Tags: python, macos, scripting

I've read many of the other answers on here to try and get this working, but for some reason it won't. I've already changed permissions and made the .py executable with `chmod +x <myscript.py>`, and I've copied the file into my /usr/local/bin which is already in my PATH by default on OSX, however, I still can't execute the script unless I'm in the directory where it's located.

In addition, I'm a little confused on how the header works. I currently have `#!/usr/bin/python` because when I changed it to `#!/usr/local/bin` to match the directory, when I ran the script my terminal said I had a "bad interpreter."

I know this topic has been on here a lot, but the other fixes haven't worked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error do you get when trying to run this script outside of `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: The terminal just says '-bash: ./Untitled.py: No such file or directory'

Comment: and how exactly are you trying to run it?

Answer (score 2):

If you run your script like this:

```
./Untitled.py
```

Bash will try to find the script in the current directory -- because you've invoked the script with a file path (a relative one in this case).

However, if you run the script like this:

```
Untitled.py
```

Bash will search your `PATH` for an executable with that name. Assuming that you've made the script executable (with `chmod`) and that script resides in a directory in your `PATH`, the script should run.

Regarding the she-bang line, rather than hard-coding to a specific Python (`/usr/bin/python`), a more common approach would be this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Your script will be executed by whichever Python is active at the moment (for example, you might be using `virtualenv` or `pyenv` to switch between Pythons, depending on your current project).

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize the difference between running ./Untitled.py and Untitled.py